# Avoid onRowClick event in certain column of rich:dataTable

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces, onrowclick

I have a `rich:dataTable` which contains 4 columns.

The first one is a `selectBooleanCheckBox`, which fires an event called "CheckEvent" (just for the example) into the bean.

Meanwhile, the dataTable also supports the `onRowClick` event, which fires "onRowClick" on the bean.

The problem I'm facing is that when I click on the first column (the check one), the `onRowClick` also fires. This certainly is a problem in this situation: if a row has the check selected and I just want to deselect it, the `onRowClick` highlights the row, a behaviour I don't want.

I've tried to define the `oOnRowClick` event inside the other three `rich:columns`, but what I achieve this way is nothing; that the event doesn't even trigger, so there's no `onRowClick` for the datatable.

Trying to make the logic via the bean doesn't work either, since I don't know which column is pushed when I enter the `onRowClick()` method.

I'm really desperate about this. Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: You placed back [javascript] tag. I disagree this. [javascript] users are not capable of answering this question as they have no knowledge of [jsf]. They are not able to tell how exactly the RichFaces-specific `onRowClick` event is represented in HTML/JS context. The [jsf] and particularly [richfaces] users, on the other hand, do have knowledge of [javascript] and, more importantingly, RichFaces-generated HTML/JS output. If you were able to boil down and demonstrate the problem into some jsfiddle demo, then of course [javascript] is applicable, but [jsf]/[richfaces] is in turn questionable ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

onrowclick adds `onclick` on the table row, if you don't want it to fire you have to prevent the click event on the checkbox from bubbling up to the row, e.g.:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="event.stopPropagation()" … />
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it ; )

Answer (score 1):

I can see that this 
`<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="event.stopPropagation()" … />`
works perfectly for solving the QA's Problem with the `selectBooleanCheckbox`.

Would something similar work, if the Column that is not supposed to react to the onclick Event contains a clickable Icon, that is supposed to execute a different function? See the example below:

```
<rich:panel headerClass="panelHeader" styleClass="panel">
    <f:facet name="header">Header</f:facet>
    <rich:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myModel}" var="k">

        <a4j:support event="onRowClick" action="#{myAction.selectItem(k, facesContext.viewRoot.viewId)}"
                            reRender="myTable"/>

            <rich:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Normal Column - should be clickable"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{k.name}"/>
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column >
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Only Click on Icon should react to Mouseclick"/>
                </f:facet>
                <s:graphicImage value="/img/bin_closed.gif">
                    <a4j:support event="onclick"
                                 action="#{myAction.deleteItem(k)}"
                                 reRender="myTable"
                                 ajaxSingle="true" limitToList="true"
                                 onsubmit="if(!confirm('Really?')) { return false; }" />/>
                </s:graphicImage>
            </rich:column>

    </rich:dataTable>

</rich:panel>
```